# Ploting an x-y graph with "four" axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

Generally, I'm trying to understand whether *matplotlib* actually has this capability.

I have a ***speed*** (on x axis) in mph vs.  ***power*** (on y axis) in kW graph, to which I need to add a ***rotations*** (on second y axis, **to the right**) and another ***speed*** (on second x axis, **up on the top**) in km/h.

Power in kW is in correlation with speed in mph, while rotations is in correlation with Power, and second speed (on second x axis) is just the first speed multiplied with a convertion coefficient.

***So, my question is - how can I plot a x-y plot in matplotlib with two x and two y axis?***

Comment: @DNA - Well, if you want you *could* make rotations in correlation with speed, but it is not usually done. Rotations are always presented in correlation to power. It is the industry convention, that has been that way for decades now. So it is not technically, independent, as you put it, but practically, yes.

Comment: If I understand right, you want two X-axes so you can show speed in different units - OK. You want two Y axes, so you can show both rotations and power - but are you assuming that power is linearly proportional to rotation speed? This isn't true in any real system.

Comment: Oh, I guess you mean output power (of something?). OK, that does make sense now!

Comment: @DNA - As a general case, to expand - can I plot two independent (power vs. speed) and (rotations vs. speed) graphs on the same plot. Never mind that "it doesn't make sense" ... I'll worry about that part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking for [twinx](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.twinx) and [twiny](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.twiny)?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = range(1,21)
plt.xlabel('1st X')
plt.ylabel('1st Y')
plt.plot(x,x,'r') # against 1st x, 1st y
plt.axis([0,50,0,25])
plt.twinx()
plt.ylabel('2nd Y')
plt.plot(x,x,'g') # against 1st x, 2nd y
plt.axis([0,50,0,20])
plt.twiny()
plt.xlabel('2nd X')
plt.plot(x,x,'b') # against 2nd x, 2nd y
plt.axis([0,10,0,20])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

My apologies, I misunderstood.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.axes import Axes

rect = 0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_axes(rect)

t = np.arange(0.01, 10.0, 0.01)

ax1.plot(t, np.exp(t), 'b-') # Put your speed/power plot here
ax1.set_xlabel('Speed (mph)', color='b')
ax1.set_ylabel('Power', color='b')

ax2 = fig.add_axes(rect, frameon=False)
ax2.yaxis.tick_right()
ax2.yaxis.set_label_position('right')
ax2.xaxis.tick_top()
ax2.xaxis.set_label_position('top')

ax2.plot(t, np.sin(2*np.pi*t), 'r-') # Put your speed/rotation plot here
ax2.set_xlabel('Speed (kmph)', color='r')
ax2.set_ylabel('Rotations', color='r')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You could also have used `fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2)` instead of constructing `fig`, `ax1`, `ax2` separately.